# Hiding Access 2000 Toolbar button

Tags: microsoft-access

Is there a way to hide a Access 2000 toolbar button? I have looked in the properties for a toolbar button in design view, but there does not appear to be any properties listed that relate to what I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to hide the button permanently or conditionally, based on other things?

Comment: conditionally based on a tag property of a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198464

Instead of using the Enable property like they use, I just substituted with the Visible property.